# I have date column in pyspark STRING format and i want to typecast into date format

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have date in date column like maintained below

```
date column
01-JAN-22
```

In string format and I want to type cast into date format.

I have tried many ways using pyspark functions and SQL functions but not getting output its showing null.

Can anybody help me to solve this query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date).

The variaous datetime patterns for formatting and parsing are documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01-JAN-22"]], schema=["date column"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn("date column", F.to_date("date column", "d-MMM-yy"))

df.printSchema()
[Out]:
root
 |-- date column: date (nullable = true)

print(df.schema)
[Out]:
StructType([StructField('date column', DateType(), True)])
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?